# FuelPHP + JSON + Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, fuelphp

For example, when I use `Model_Trabalhos::query()->related('categoria')`, I Get a normal JSON like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "categoria_id": "2",
    "empresa": "Veja",
    "nome": "Veja",
    "thumb_pequena": "jobs/digital/veja/thumb.jpg",
    "thumb_grande": "jobs/digital/veja/thumb_grande.jpg",
    "destaque": "0",
    "categoria": {
        "id": "2",
        "titulo": "Digital"
    },
    "imagens": {
        "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "url": "jobs/digital/veja/1.png",
            "legenda": "",
            "job_id": "1"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "2",
            "url": "jobs/digital/veja/2.png",
            "legenda": "",
            "job_id": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

instead, I wanted to receive back this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "categoria_id": "2",
        "empresa": "Valor Econômico",
        "nome": "Novo Site",
        "thumb_pequena": "jobs/digital/valor-economico/thumb.jpg",
        "thumb_grande": "jobs/digital/valor-economico/thumb_grande.jpg",
        "destaque": "1",
        "categoria": {
            "id": "2",
            "titulo": "Digital"
        },
        "imagens": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "url": "jobs/digital/valor-economico/1.png",
                "legenda": "",
                "job_id": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You see? In the second case, it's wrapped in an array, and I wanted to know if there's a function in FuelPHP native that wrap the content to be ordered.

I'm in trouble... I'm using FuelPHP + ORM to get all my records from a database and generating a JSON to use with JavaScript and Ajax, but in Chrome, the JSON is not following the order by defined, is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: There just might be, if you show us what are you doing, what you get and what you expect.

Comment: Cam you please post the sample expected JSON and actualy what you are getting in chrome , we can definately help you

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that the choice of browser has any influence on how the ORM would generate a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting your information in a certain way you could follow that query with a foreach loop that would add them to an array of arrays (translated to an array of JSON objects) once converted to JSON.

```
$query = Model_Trabalhos::query()->related('categoria')

$categories = array();
foreach ($query as $category) {
    $categories[] = array(
        'id' => $category->id,
         ...
    );
}

return $categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but i had the same problem now and colud resolve like the answer that i posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34242106/5670195.

In case it is a function that converts into simple array, the objects returned as the relationship of ORM.