# How do I return JSON Arrays instead of objects using FuelPHP's ORM and Controller_Rest

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

```
Controller_Something extends Controller_Rest {
  public function get_something() {    
    $query = Model_Something::query()->related('hasMany')->get();
    return $this->response($query);
  }
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  stuff: here,
  looks: good,
  hasMany: {
    151251: {
      id: 151251,
      other: stuff
    }
  }
}
```

I want the relations as arrays:

```
{
  stuff: here,
  looks: good,
  hasMany: [
    {
      id: 151251,
      other: stuff
    }
  ]
}
```

This happens because the ORM returns related result arrays with keys corresponding to the record's PKEY, and JSON interprets this as an Object. I want these arrays to go through `array_values()` or something, so the JSON result will use Array.

**Currently** I am doing this to "solve" the problem:

```
$res = Format::forge($result_set)->to_array();
$res['hasMany'] = array_values($res['hasMany']);
return $this->response($res);
```

But this is only useful to one or two levels, where I know the data will be.

If there are relations that are not guaranteed, I don't what to have to error-check every potential subset of a  complex Model.

I just want all the one-to-many arrays to be keyed sequentially instead of by the records PKEY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: you can't unless you create a hook in `Query:hydrate` https://github.com/fuel/orm/blob/1.7/develop/classes/query.php#L1083, or shadowing the `Query` class with some implementation that returns the very same results except for `hydrate`.

Answer (score 1):

`$query = Model_Something::find()->related('hasMany');`

returns a query object in < 1.6, an exception in 1.6, and null in 1.6.1+. So I assume you do something else that produces that result.

If you want arrays as a result instead of objects, you need to convert the result. You can do that by calling `to_array()` on a model object, or by using the Format class to convert an array of model objects to an array:
`$result = \Format::forge($result)->to_array();`

Comment: `Format::forge()` isn't what I want; the outgoing JSON is still based on an id-keyed array, and will be expressed as a JSON object, not an array. I'll add my current workaround to show this.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `find()` is deprecated in favor of `query()` :)

Comment: you want an indexed array I understand. That is not going to be produced, the ORM uses the array index value to store the PK of the related record, so it can be found back. array_values() is probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

```
function object_to_array($data){
         $new_data2= array();
         $keys   =   array_keys((array)$data);
         foreach ($keys as $key)
        {
            $value  =   $data[$key];

            if(is_numeric($key))
            {
                $new_data2[]    =   object_to_array($value);

            }elseif(is_string($value) || is_null($value))
            {
                $new_data2[$key]    =   $data[$key];
            }else
            {
                $new_data2[$key]    =   object_to_array($value);
            }

        }

        return $new_data2;
    }
$formattedArray  =   \Format::forge(Model_Product::query()->get())->to_array();

$cleanData=object_to_array($formattedArray);

echo \Format::forge($cleanData)->to_json();
```

This way checks the array key; if key is number and value is object or array clean key

Comment: While this code might solve the issue you should always accompany your code with an explanation as well.

Comment: I agree you but i have bad english

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically it is possible to be done. Following the model below, but for very deep relationships is not interesting by the complexity of the algorithm.

Model:

```
class Model_Something extends \Orm\Model
{
    ...

    public function relatedAsArray()
    {
        $this->relationsAsArray($this->_data_relations);
    }

    private function relationsAsArray(&$relations)
    {
        foreach ($relations as $key => $relation) {
            foreach ($relation as $fields) {
                foreach ($fields as $field) {
                    if (isset($field->_data_relations)) {
                        $this->relationsAsArray($field->_data_relations);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (is_array($relation)) {
                $relations[$key] = array_values($relation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call of method:

```
$something = Model_Something::find($somethingId, array('related' => array('hasMany', 'hasMany.hasOthers')));

$something->relatedAsArray();
```

The result was exactly like you wanted.

Result:

```
{
  stuff: here,
  looks: good,
  hasMany: [
    {
      id: 151251,
      other: stuff,
      hasOthers: [
          {
            id: 12312,
            field: other
          }, ...
      ]
    }, ...
  ]
}
```